# IBM Watson Discovery service - sharepoint online url issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, watson-discovery

I am trying to crawl the Sharepoint online using WDS and ingest the documents thereon to WDS. I get the following issue while I try crawling on the sharepoint online.

The connector did not catch an exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "FI"

Please help me resolve this issue. All configurations are as per documentation.

Thanks & Regards,
Subhashni

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: Hi Priyal, Thanks for the response. I have not written any code. But this is all configuration in the seed and connector configuration files. I have followed the instructions in the documentation provided for the same.